# Flutter release.apk does not start

Tags: flutter, apk

i developed my first flutter app in order to publish it on Google Play and Apple Store. The app is working fine when it is started through a command, e.g `flutter run`. When the app is run tapping the app icon on the screen, the app info are shown and does not start. Same if I install the release apk.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

EIDT:

As suggested, running `flutter run --release` shows me the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26925): Process: com.example.app_flutter, PID: 26925
E/AndroidRuntime(26925): java.lang.AssertionError: AssertionError (GSON 2.8.5): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: READY
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.Gson.w(Unknown Source:73)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.Gson.x(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.Gson.t(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.Gson.s(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at u2.e$a.a(Unknown Source:84)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at u2.f$e.onTaskCompleted(Unknown Source:42)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication$17.onTaskCompleted(Unknown Source:15)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication$17.onTaskCompleted(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.commandCallbackOnTaskCompleted(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.access$900(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher$3.run(Unknown Source:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925): Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: READY
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$EnumTypeAdapter.<init>(Unknown Source:87)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.create(Unknown Source:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.Gson.l(Unknown Source:74)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(Unknown Source:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.c(Unknown Source:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.Gson.w(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        ... 17 more
E/AndroidRuntime(26925): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: READY
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1604)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$EnumTypeAdapter.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(26925):        ... 23 more
```

I am not at the release yet, I am just trying to have a runnint protoype on my phone.

As suggested by other users, I had to fix the build Types link mentioned [here](https://github.com/nodriver-ai/flutter_azure_b2c/issues/16):

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
```

Now running `flutter run --release` does not show any error, but starting the app by tapping the icon, info are still shown.

Comment: try to debug with `flutter run --release` and print the function that may caused error. you may find any error in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I added the stacktrace. However, it does not help me.

Comment: if your are running it in the release mode have you added the release keys?

Comment: can you try connecting your device via usb and run flutter install and check if you are able to install the application and run it on phone

Comment: Well, I'm not at the release point yet, I am just trying to have a running prototype without any USB cable plugged

Comment: @Nagual I dont think so, I did not add it.

Comment: Actually, Im not using it, it comes from `flutter_azure_b2c` dependency. I fear the problem is this library.

Comment: The release mode is not crashing anymore, but without the cable the app is still showing the app info instead.

Comment: I just noticed that the appm starts only if i run it by command. If I open the app by tapping the icon on the phone, the info are shown. Indipendently it the usb is plugged or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the problem is related to flutter, instead it is a AndroiManifest error. Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72805787/android-app-capacitor-opens-app-info-screen-instead-of-opening-the-app).

this was my Manifest intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="msauth"
    android:host="com.example.app_flutter"
    android:path="/hiddent54t54=" />
</intent-filter>
```

I had to remove the `data tag:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now it works.